# Using pdfjs-dist on vercel (serverless function)

Tags: node.js, vercel, pdf.js

I'm trying to fetch and parse PDF file using the `pdfjs-dist` package in node runtime inside the Vercel Serverless Function.

Code (TypeScript):

```js
import * as pdfjs from "pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf";
...

const document = await pdfjs.getDocument(url).promise;
...
```

Locally, when running `vercel dev` everything works OK. But after the deployment, when accessing the remote endpoint, I get following error:

`Error: Setting up fake worker failed: \"Cannot find module './pdf.worker.js'`

Any idea what can be causing this difference between local Vercel execution and the deployed version?

- Local node version: v16.16
- Vercel node version: 16.x
- "pdfjs-dist": "^3.0.279"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution:

1: After compiling, you need to manually change this line of code. Vercel supports specifying custom compilation steps in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "now-build": "node build.js"
}
```

2: The build.js file is used to complete the above replacement:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dir = 'node_modules/pdfjs-dist/es5/build/pdf.js';
const content = fs.readFileSync(dir, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
fs.writeFileSync(dir, content.replace('"./pdf.worker.js";', `__dirname + "/pdf.worker.js";`))
```

3. Redeploy and enjoy! :)

Comment: Hey, yes I already found the solution - same as yours. I just forgot to update it. Marked your message as the answer, thank you!

PS: I had to do more changes as the function bundle was in the end over the 50 mega limit, but that's another story :)

Comment: What triggers `now-build`?